# creating the sequence 000,111,222 ... in c++

Tags: c++, for-loop, sequence

I want my `std::cout`  to print `000111222333 ...`, but what i'm getting instead is `0111222333 ...`, and i don't know why, here is my code:

```
int threeCounter =1;
int outPut =0;
for (int i =0; i<300;i++){

    if(threeCounter > 3 ){
        outPut++ ;
        threeCounter=1;

    }

    cout << outPut << endl;
    threeCounter++;

}
```

I tried the very same code in matlab, and it's producing the correct sequence:

```
threeCounter=1;
outPut =0;
for i =1:300

    if(threeCounter >3)

        outPut=outPut+1;
        threeCounter=1;

    end
    disp(outPut)
    threeCounter=threeCounter+1;

end
```

Comment: The "very same" code? It´s not. And stop thinking that all languages have same semantics.

Comment: I cannot reproduce your error.

Comment: The leading zeros of numbers may not get displayed.  See the `fill` I/O manipulator.

Comment: all correct: http://ideone.com/8evkQd

Comment: @Thomas Matthews, i think this is it, it was so confusing.

Comment: If you change your printout to before the `if` condition, everything then works as intended except you do not print the third `99`, so you're left with `98 98 98 99 99`. This makes sense since it will not iterate the loop the third time, but may be a clue as to why you do not get the initial `0`.

Comment: @Apastrix Did the code in answer solve your problem?

Comment: @ shruti1810 No, it didn't compile, an error about to_string poped out, when i looked it out, i found that it's a known bug for MinGW to not take to_string as a member of std, Anyway, the code i posted was correct, the display via cout was omitting the first zeros, so thanks anyway!

Answer (score 0):

Try this code in C++:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
for (int i =0; i<300;i++){
   string outPut = "";
   int threeCounter =0;
    while(threeCounter < 3 ){
        outPut = outPut+to_string(i) ;
        threeCounter+=1;

    }

    cout << outPut;
    threeCounter++;

}

}
```

Comment: The `to_string` is not available before C++11.  Tell your compiler to use C++11 features.